# Saving data in json permanently using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

My problem is when a user hits the submit button, i want the data in that form to go into a json file, but not temporary, like whenever i go back to that file i will find the data there.

Note: I don't want to download any data in the client side.
Ty for reading

Comment: you can use the localstorage to persist data